# Spring GET controller collection of custom object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

So here's the deal, I'm trying to create a search for an entity Foo like this:

```
@GetMapping(value="/search", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Set<FooDto>> search(@RequestParam final Set<FooCriteriaDto> criteriaDtos) {

    // Call the Foo's service with the criteria's object, process it, map the result and return it
}
```

The problem is I can not make use of this endpoint.

What I'd tried so far:

1. Removing the @RequestParam

   1.1. `[{field: foo}, {field: bar}]` - (result) > No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.Set

   1.2 `criteriaDtos[0].field=foo&criteriaDtos[1].field=bar` - (result) > Same error as 1.1
2. With the @RequestParam

   2.1 `[{field: foo}, {field: bar}]` - (result) > Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'FooCriteriaDto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

   2.2 `[{"field": "foo"}, {"field":"bar"}]` - (result) > Same error as 2.1

   2.3 `criteriaDtos[0].field=foo&criteriaDtos[1].field=bar` - (result) > Required Set parameter 'criteriaDtos' is not present

I thought of using a POST with a *RequestBody* instead, but I rather not to (since this is just asking data, not creating).

Any ideas on how to achieve this, or why it's just not possible at all?

Edit:

use case:

The endpoint is a search for an entity, the reason to ask for a Set of criterias is you can have multiple filters.

ex: [{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar", "age": 14}]

That set of criterias should return the entities who's name is "foo" OR it's name is "bar" AND it's age is "14".

In other words between criterias (items of the collection) the query uses an OR, but for each of the fields inside the criteria the query uses an AND operator.

Comment: Please include an example of what your intended input is.

Comment: That's what I want to know, which is the required input (as parameter) for this endpoint to work as expected (return 200 with the provided information), either with or without @RequestParam.

Comment: It is not usual to pass complex object as query parameters in the first place, and so it's unclear what you're trying to map _in_. If you describe what you're trying to actually accomplish (just passing a list of complex criteria?), we may be able to help more usefully (e.g., "use Querydsl").

Comment: Change to `POST` request with `@RequestBody`

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I now understand what you mean. Edited

Comment: @Holinc I'd like to avoid to use a POST if it's possible since like I mention on the post, this endpoint will not create a resource.

Comment: I think I understand better. The idiomatic way to express this in HTTP _is to make separate requests_ for your "or"s; that is, use all the parameters in a single request as a set of criteria (I will suggest Querydsl at this point, especially since it has integration with Spring MVC and Spring Data), and then make multiple requests.

Comment: You can not pass the complex parameters by @RequestParam. Or you can try to implement to resolve your parameter by implementing `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Comment: If you create @RequestBody You can pass this and map to the list inside the custom Request object that you will get. That is create a SearchRequest class and put this Set inside it. After that retrieve that set in your method and use it as you need